# Commands in Paramiko block due to script execution time

Tags: python, session, ssh, paramiko

hello guys i have three server and i mange it from SSH so i made this script  to run my Register script "Register.py" so everyday i turn on Register mode so the problem how i can login to multiple SSH connection without close the other

```
import paramiko
import os
ZI1={"ip":"192.168.1.2","pass":"Administrator"}
ZI2={"ip":"192.168.1.3","pass":"AdminTeachers"}
ZI3={"ip":"192.168.1.4","pass":"AdminStudents"}
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
for F1 in ZI1:
    ssh.connect(ZI1["ip"],username='root', password=ZI1["pass"])
    ssh.exec_command('./register.py -time 6') #6 hour so the script still working for 6 hours
    ssh.close()
for F2 in ZI2:
    ssh.connect(ZI2["ip"],username='root', password=ZI2["pass"])
    ssh.exec_command('./register.py -time 6')
    ssh.close()
for F3 in ZI3:
    ssh.connect(ZI2["ip"],username='root', password=ZI2["pass"])
    ssh.exec_command('./register.py -time 6')
    ssh.close()
```

so what i have to do to open 3 sessions without stopping script !!

Comment: Have you tried creating 3 instances of paramiko.SSHClient() and placing them in the separator threads?

Comment: @Johnsyweb, he is asking a different question about the same script.  It doesn't look like a dup to me

Comment: @Mike Pennington, @jack-X: I sit corrected, with apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is using Thread if you need do some action based on return of Register.py

See example:

```
import paramiko
import os
import sys
from threading import Thread

SERVER_LIST = [{"ip":"192.168.1.2","pass":"Administrator"},{"ip":"192.168.1.4","pass":"AdminStudents"},{"ip":"192.168.1.3","pass":"AdminTeachers"}]



class ExecuteRegister(Thread):
    def __init__ (self,options):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.options = options       
        self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())



    def run(self):
        try:
           self.ssh.connect(self.options['ip'],username='root', password=self.options["pass"])
           self.ssh.exec_command('./register.py -time 6') #6 hour so the script still working for 6 hours
           self.ssh.close()
        except:
           print sys.exc_info()



for server in SERVER_LIST:
    Register = ExecuteRegister(server)
    Register.start()
```

Comment: mr.olarva does your code make the script still working without close it? (session still open?) also i got that error ! `(<class 'socket.er
onnected party did
onnection failed b
ct at 0x02888D78>)` thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/tutorial.html). It may help you with working with SSH connections.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are currently doing it blocks beacuse you are not logging out of the hosts for six hours.

### Multiprocessing:

If you need to see return codes from the script, you should open your connections to each host using [python's multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html).

### nohup:

Another method (that will not allow you to see the script's return value via `paramiko`) is to use `nohup` to disassociate the script from the shell.  That will put it in the background and allow you to logout.  To do this use...

```
    ssh.exec_command('nohup ./register.py -time 6 &')
```

### Typos:

BTW, you had typos in the last loop... `ZI2` should be `ZI3` in the last loop... furthermore, the `for`-loops are unnecessary... I fixed your very last iteration...  Acks to @johnsyweb for spotting more of the OP's typos than I did...

```
ssh.connect(ZI3["ip"],username='root', password=ZI3["pass"])
ssh.exec_command('./register.py -time 6')   # <------------- missing s in ssh
ssh.close()
```

Comment: Up !!! please help me i got error `(<class 'socket.error'>, error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the t
arget machine actively refused it'), <traceback object at 0x0290BDC8>)`

Comment: That's not the only error in that last for-loop, it is also referencing `ZI2`, presumably a copy & paste error from the previous block. More pertinently: why are you using a `for`-loop here? There's no iteration other than doing everything twice (because there are two elements in that `dict`). I maintain that `cron` is the best approach here.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, I agree with what you said... I wrote this as I was preparing to walk out the door for work this morning; I should have spotted the issues with the `for` loop.  As for `cron`, perhaps that is true, but if this is a homework assignment, he may be handcuffed to `paramiko`... I will leave that for the OP to comment on.

Comment: He he. I know what it's like. I made a similar mistake by marking this as a duplicate when I was rushing off to do something else.